# Make Drupal menu router to ignore a path that belongs to another website

Tags: routes

I have Drupal running at `http://api.site.com`. My conf file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@site.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal
        ServerName api.site.com
        ServerAlias api.site.com
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/drupal>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have another website at /var/www/html/documentation/api/v3/rest but without a conf file.

When I navigate to http://api.site.com/documentation, drupal takes precedence with a "Page not found" error. That is pretty much expected.

My question is, how do I make the site at /var/www/html/documentation/api/v3/rest to take precedence instead of drupal?

I followed the doc at `http://drupal.org/node/30334` ,  but it's not working for me yet.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: If Drupal's docroot is `/var/www/html/drupal`, and the second site is at `/var/www/html/documentation/api/v3/`, then the documentation site isn't actually online (you'd need to move it to `/var/www/html/drupal/documentation/api/v3/`). Are you sure those are the right paths?

Comment: Thanks @Clive. The documentation site is not a Drupal site. As an update, I have added a vhost for the documentation site.

Comment: If you want the documentation site to be available under the Drupal domain, I think you'll need to move the files underneath the Drupal web root. You can't specify a sub-folder of a domain as the ServerName/Alias in a vhost as far as I know

Comment: Does that mean I can't achieve what I want if the documentation is at /var/www/html/drupal/documentation ?

Comment: I would've thought so...Drupal's .htaccess it set up not to rewrite for existing files/folders. And if you've got an .htaccess under the documentation folder that'll take precedence anyway. We've got full Wordpress sites running under sub-folders of Drupal web roots so I can't see there being a problem

Comment: Okay I moved the docs to Drupal's root at /var/www/html/drupal/documentation/api/v3/rest . Please, any hint on what goes into the .htaccess file for this?

Comment: Can't really say without knowing the folder structure. If you're not rewriting URLs (just accessing files directly) you shouldn't need to add one

Comment: I'm not rewriting files. The files at /var/www/html/documentation/api/v3/rest are plain html files . I tested with api.site.com/documentation/api/v3/rest but It's showing up Drupal's home page instead of the content at [DRUPAL_HOME]/documentation/api/v3/rest

Comment: Try browsing to an html file directly; if the files are in the right place there's no reason Drupal would even get involved

Comment: Thanks @Clive. I did. Drupal looks for /documentation in menu router and returns "page not found". Typical Drupal stuff.